# "trainer" in the context of educational technology

Tags: word-choice, translation

In English, it is perfectly fine to use expressions like "vocabulary *trainer*" or "grammar *trainer*" to denominate a certain type of software that offers interactive exercises (often in the form of drill and practice).

The publishing house PONS apparently uses the expression "*trainer* lessicale" to translate "vocabulary *trainer*": https://itunes.apple.com/it/app/pons-trainer-lessicale/id452121028?l=it

Interestingly, Google searches for the word "*trainer*" return very few results that concern the context of e-learning.

- Does the use of the word “*trainer*” appear strange in this context?
- Why do you think PONS chose "*trainer* lessicale" over "*trainer* di
  *vocaboli*"?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: «Does the use of the word “trainer” appear strange in this context?» - Do you mean in Italian? Yes, very much so, because it is not an Italian word, and most people – me included – wouldn't understand it.

Comment: @DaG: How would you translate "vocabulary _trainer_" into Italian?

Comment: Since the notion is new, it would be necessary to create a new phrase: “allenatore lessicale” seems the most obvious one, but I am sure someone else can do better.

Comment: @DaG: Thank you. And how would you translate "grammar _trainer_" or "conjugation _trainer_" into Italian?

Comment: In this case I would use “esercitatore”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most literal (valid) translation, as pointed out by egreg, would probably be *Esercitatore lessicale* .

But it does sound "clunky".

A more natural (and less literal) translation that I would use is possibly *Eserciziario di lessico* or *eserciziario lessicale*.]

For the other two you mentioned, you could use the same schema and go with *eserciziario di grammatica* and *eserciziario di (sulle?) coniugazioni* , though the latter is also a bit odd-sounding. Probably sounds better with *sulle* instead of *di* in this case.